# Changes to make in Delphi source library so as the resulting .dll is recognized as a different dll when registered in windows

Tags: delphi, dll, com

I have the source in delphi of an open source electrical solver (OpenDSS)
Normally, when installing OpenDSS, the engine is registered as a COM component.

I want to compile the engine 8 times making 8 differente dll's that internally are exactly the same. Why? because I want to use 8 mono-core solvers at once to perform monte carlo simulations.

The problem is that by simply renaming the dll's and registering them, windows recognize them as the same COM component. So the question is; What changes shall I make in the source so when I compile the library I cheat windows?

I hope que question is clear enough, and thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty strange question. A far better solution to the problem would be to ensure that the component was threadsafe. A not quite so good solution would be to run multiple processes rather than multiple threads. You could use reg free COM to load 8 different copies of the DLL. 

However, the answer to your question is that you need to change the CLSID in each of the 8 copies. It's a really horrid solution. Can't you find a better solution.

Comment: Well, I definitelly agree with you that the best would be to make the solver thread safe, however, it is legacy code that works, and making such changes require to know the source in depth. So I came up with this weird solution.

Comment: Just removing all the global vars and making them params is usually enough. Often requires no deep understanding. I once made a threadsafe version of Fortran ARPACK code that way.

Answer (score 2):

Naively, the answer to your question is to make eight different versions of the code that are identical apart from having different CLSIDs. Keep all the IIDS of the exposed interfaces the same, but vary the CLSIDs. That allows you to register eight distinct COM servers with different CLSIDs to identify them. But you request the same IID from each COM object that you create.

This is a pretty vile solution though. It doesn't scale very well. It's expensive of memory. It's just really unwieldy. It would surely be possible to make the code threadsafe. Usually this can be done by locating the globals and dealing with them. Typically by converting them into parameters or state.

If you cannot manage that then you could create a stub executable to allow the server to run out-of-proc. Then instantiate separate instances of the out-of-proc server.